# pdflatex.exe: The memory dump file could not be found. pdflatex.exe: Data: pdflatex.fmt

Tags: compiling

I'm getting the same error message that a lot of people have run into.  I just reinstalled MiKTeX 2.9 and I am now trying to use TeXstudio and every time I try to compile or build I get the following error:

```
Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "gov30_midterm_2017".tex

pdflatex.exe: The memory dump file could not be found. pdflatex.exe: Data: pdflatex.fmt

Process exited with error(s)
```

Here is what I'm trying to compile:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\usepackage{geometry}                % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\geometry{letterpaper}                   % ... or a4paper or a5paper or ... 
%\geometry{landscape}                % Activate for for rotated page geometry
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}    % Activate to begin paragraphs with an empty line rather than an indent
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\renewcommand{\mp}[1]{\textbf{\color{red}#1}}
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{`convert #1 `dirname #1`/`basename #1 .tif`.png}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\firstpageheadrule
\runningheadrule
\firstpageheader{\sc Gov 30}{\sc Midterm Exam}{\sc October 4, 2017}
\runningheader{\sc Gov 30}{\sc Midterm Exam} {\sc Page \thepage\ of \numpages}
\firstpagefooter{}{}{}
\runningfooter{}{\iflastpage{\sc End of Exam}{}}{}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.2in}

\newcommand{\answerbox}{
\begin{flushright}
\fbox{\parbox{1in}{
\vspace{.1in}
\thequestion.
\vspace{.1in}}}
\end{flushright} 
}


%\printanswers
\begin{document} 

\vspace{1in}

\begin{center} 
{\bfseries \LARGE Course} 

{\bfseries \LARGE Midterm Exam}

\end{center} 
\section*{Instructions}

You have 55 minutes to complete this exam. The exam will start at 11:05 and end at 12:00. Please read each question carefully and write your answers neatly, using pen, not pencil. This exam is \textbf{closed book}.  You may not use any books, notes, electronic devices, or any other resources, or confer with any other person.

The exam consists of two sections: term identifications and short essays.  Read the instructions for each section carefully. Write your answers in two blue books. Use one blue book for all of the identifications, and one blue book for the essays.  \textbf{Make sure to write your name and section on both blue books.}

\vspace{3in}
\begin{center}
\fbox{\fbox{\parbox{6.3in}{\centering\parbox{6.2in}{
\vspace{.1in}
\textbf{Do not turn over this sheet until you are instructed to do so.}
\vspace{.1in}
 }}}}
\end{center}

\newpage
\fullwidth{\Large \textbf{Section I. Term Identifications (30 points)}}
\begin{center}
\fbox{\fbox{\parbox{6.3in}{\centering\parbox{6.2in}{
\vspace{.1in}
In a short paragraph, identify and discuss the significance of the following five terms.  Each identification is worth six points.  \textit{Be sure your definition connects to topics discussed in the course}. This section should take you approximately 25 minutes.
\vspace{.1in}
 }}}}
\end{center}

\vspace{.5in}
\begin{choices}
\choice Option
\choice Option
\choice Option
\choice Option
\choice Option
\end{choices}

\vspace{.5in}
\fullwidth{\Large \textbf{Section II. Short Essay (35 points each)}}
\fbox{\fbox{\parbox{6.3in}{\centering\parbox{6.2in}{
\vspace{.1in}
Please read the prompts below and answer \textbf{TWO OF THE THREE} following questions in two \textbf{short} essays.  Be sure to define any terms that you use and to connect your answer to topics discussed in the course.  This section should take you approximately 30 minutes.
\vspace{.1in}
 }}}}
\vspace{.5in}

Question 1?\\
\\

Question 2.\\
\\

Question 3?


\vfill
\begin{center}
\fbox{\fbox{\parbox{6.3in}{\centering\parbox{6.2in}{
\vspace{.1in}
\textbf{Write your name and section on the front of each blue book before turning in your exam.}\vspace{.1in}
 }}}}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I have never been able to successfully compile or build on my home PC.  I'm running Windows 10.  I'm not particularly savvy on the language here and my programming skills are almost non-existent so I would appreciate detailed guidance if possible.  I should also say that this compiles perfectly on my laptop and as such, I'm not in a huge hurry to get this resolved, but I would much prefer to prepare documents on my home PC than my laptop.  To the degree possible I've tried all the recommended solutions on similar posts, but I was unable to comment there as I just started my account and I guess I don't have enough clout to comment yet.  I uninstalled both MiKTeX and TeXstudio and reinstalled them, I restarted my computer, I inserted

```
"C:\Users\Chris\initexmf --dump"
```

in the command prompt and it output "initexmf: No formats.ini exists.", I've tried opening both programs as and not as administrator, I've gone into MiKTeX settings and successfully updated formats, I've gone into MiKTeX Package Manager and successfully Synchronized under the Repository dropdown.  As far as I could tell I've tried every solution and no matter what I do it won't compile the changes I make.  When it builds it just builds an older document without implementing any changes.  Thank you for your time and assistance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you refresh the FNDB? What happens if you compile from the command line?

Comment: Stop doing things, get some data first. Most importantly pathes. What do you get when you do `echo %path%` on the command line? Where is miktex-settings (admin)?

Comment: What's the FNDB and how do I go about compiling from the command line?  I'm not sure what you mean about command line.  Do you mean the windows command prompt?  Or is it something in TexStudio? Thanks!